# Visual studio project to MonoDevelop

Tags: visual-studio, monodevelop

Is there a way to transfer a Visual Studio project to the MonoDevelop environment?
at [FAQ - MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Can_I_import_my_Visual_Studio_2K5.2b_project_into_MonoDevelop.3f) it is said that:

> MonoDevelop can open, manipulate and save MSBuild-based projects directly in mopst cases. In fact, since MonoDevelop 2.0 the default project format has been VS2008-style MSBuild projects, but VS2005 and VS1010 formats are also handled.

But when I try to open my (**ASP.NET Web Application**) .vbproj in MonoDevelop, I get:

***Load operation failed. Project does not support framework 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.***

Should I alter project settings, allowing different *.NETFramework* version or do I have to use some 3rd party softwares to translate my projects *config* files?

**EDIT:**(Resolved)
If your project is not that big yet, create a new project in your Microsoft Visual Studio(MVS) with .NET Framework 3.5 and then it will be possible to open it with MonoDevelop, else edit your projects Debug/Release config files and delete everything that has "4.0" information about this project, plus .vbproj file in are previous doesn't work and do the same, search for 4.0 information. (Applicable for framework 4.0)

OR

Change your project settings as it is described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: _[sarcasm] I think the key word in that FAQ snippet is “mopst” which is an archaic term for “unpredictably some-but-not-as-many-as-you'd-hope”._  Like many things in Mono.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of MonoDevelop are you using? MonoDevelop 2.8 can open .NET 4.0 projects (I believe 2.6 can as well). In fact, in 2.8 .NET 4.0 is the default for all new projects.

Comment: Ah, just noticed you are trying to load a .vbproj. I just confirmed that MonoDevelop has .NET 4.0 framework as the default for C# projects only. When creating a new VB.NET project the version is forced to .NET 3.5. Does using a text editor to change the framework version to 3.5 in the vbproj let you open it?

Comment: I have just created a new project with .NET Framework 3.5 and tried with that one and everything worked just fine. So i am going to move some files from my another 4.0 project. Hope everything is going to work there. Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

MonoDevelop's VB.NET addin still doesn't support .NET 4.0. It would work for C# projects.

Answer (score 2):

Using a text editor, change your *.vbproj file to add the following line:

```
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to the first PropertyGroup, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

.net framework 4.0 not yet completly implemented in mono 
but includes most of the features
try to download latest version of mono and retry:)

Comment: www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: I don't think that is a compatibility issue, since I've have a ASP.Net 4.0 project and it is supported by MonoDevelop 2.10.8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in version 3.0 of MonoDevelop.
VBNET development have changed the runtime. NET
Tools> Options> Runtimes. NET
I have marked as default MONO 2.x