# Trying to work on a VB.NET project built on the 4.0 Framework in MonoDevelop

Tags: vb.net, monodevelop

I'm looking around and I "think" I'm reading conflicting statements about MonoDevelop's ability to support a VB.NET project. Some places say it's not possible yet, and other places say that you can with MonoDevelop V2.10... unfortunately I can't seem to find this elusive v2.10.

Do any of you know if this is currently possible (even if I have to install a beta)?

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MD on Windows, then VB.NET 4 is supported when you compile against .NET 4. VB.NET 4 compiler in .NET 4 installation folder will be used.

If you are working on other OS, then Mono 2.10 is needed, as only since this release Mono's VB.NET compiler starts to support 4.0 profile.

http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#VB_Compiler

Comment: Yeah, I'm on OS X, and I've installed both Mono MDK 2.10.8_3 and Mono MRE 2.10.8_3.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but if you have the latest SDK and Runtime installed (the version numbers look good according to http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html), then you should be able to configure in MonoDevelop the correct runtime to compile against (VB.NET 4). Is there any error you met?

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure how to configure it then.

Comment: http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Tips You should be able to find Runtime Options and locate the correct profile from there

Comment: I've added a couple of screenshots to my original question. I'm looking at the link you sent, and coming up short. Also, I'm opening a project that was originally written in VS2010

Comment: "Load failed" errors need to be investigated first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651449/visual-studio-project-to-monodevelop So you should be able to compile via xbuild, but cannot compile it inside MonoDevelop.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm trying to do. It's a .NET 4 project built in VS2010. Trying to open it in MD

Comment: Then you can wait till MonoDevelop guys fix this issue. Or as it is open source, you can create a fork, https://github.com/mono/monodevelop